# ClojureScript - list functions of a namespace

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

How do I list the functions/vars of a ClojureScripts namespace ?

This is a question that has an equivalent for [`Clojure`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747294/how-to-list-the-functions-of-a-namespace), but the solutions mentioned did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`clojure.repl/dir`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.repl/dir) works for me with latest ClojureScript (1.7.228)

Answer (score 2):

[ns-interns](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ns-interns) seems to do what you need. If you need the vars/fns of the current namespace, you can use [*ns*](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/*ns*) in conjunction with it.

Usage:

`(keys (ns-interns 'my-ns)) ;; All defined variables/functions of an arbitrary evaluated namespace`

`(keys (ns-interns *ns*))  ;; All defined variables/functions of the current namespace`

Note that value of *ns* differs in run time and compile time and using CIDER/REPL also affects which ns is currently set. The latter works in my `lein repl` but not in my CIDER repl for example. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19237521/6428028) has a possible solution to that issue.

Comment: alternatively, (keys (ns-publics 'my-ns)) , will list just the public mappings, which is a little easier to manage on some of the bigger modules.

Answer (score 0):

Fow now I am doing :

```
(.keys js/Object my.ns)
```

As it looks like a namespace is an js object.