# ClojureScript Eval. How to use libraries included in the calling code

Tags: namespaces, eval, clojurescript, figwheel

I have a Clojurescript program running in the browser.

It imports a number of libraries, and then I want to allow the user to enter some small clojurescript "glue-code" that calls those libraries.

I can see (from https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.js/eval)  that you call eval with four arguments, the first being the state of the environment, which is an atom. But can I actually turn my current environment with all the functions I've required from elsewhere, into an appropriate argument to eval?

**Update :**

I thought that maybe I could set the namesspace for the eval using the :ns option of the third, opts-map, argument. I set it to the namespace of my application :

```
:ns "fig-pat.core"
```

But no difference.

Looking at the console, it's definitely the case that it's trying to do the evaluation, but it's complaining that names referenced in the eval-ed code are NOT recognised :

```
WARNING: Use of undeclared Var /square
```

for example. (square is a function I'm requiring. It's visible in the application itself ie. the fig-pat.core namespace)

I then get :

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'[Learn More]
```

Which I'm assuming this the failure of eval-ed expression as a whole.

**Update 2 :**

I'm guessing this problem might actually be related to : [How can I get the Clojurescript namespace I am in from within a clojurescript program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656481/how-can-i-get-the-clojurescript-namespace-i-am-in-from-within-a-clojurescript-pr)

```
(println *ns*)
```

is just printing nil. So maybe Clojurescript can't see its own namespace.

And therefore the :ns in eval doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Calling `eval` inside a clojurescript program is part of what is called "self-hosted clojurescript".
In self-hosted clojurescript, namespaces are not available unless you implement a resolve policy. It means that have to let the browser know how to resolve the namespace e.g. loads a cljs file from a cdn.

It's not so trivial to implement namespace resolving properly.
This is explained in a cryptic way in the docstring of `load-fn` from [cljs.js namespace](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/9778b34d9e988a28c64133c4751d235bbbd3e966/src/main/cljs/cljs/js.cljs#L74).

Several tools support namespaces resolving in self-host cljs running in the browser e.g [Klipse](http://app.klipse.tech/) and [crepl](http://crepl.thegeez.net/p/guest_42213_pad)